# How to retrieve database entries by date and time in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For restricting the amount of times a user can attempt to log in with the wrong credentials, I'm trying to retrieve the entries from the database that have been entered today (preferably within last 10 minutes even) and check if 'success' is true or false.

I can't, however, retrieve the entries by date. I'm printing a list with what should be there, and by now it should be a long list, and it keeps returning empty. How should I retrieve them?

After failing to check the entire `datetime` for entries entered in the last ten minutes, I simply reverted to checking entries for today to see if I could get any results.

I have tried with 'regular' `filter_by` method and by using the extract method and both come back completely empty (See code posted). It doesn't return an error or anything, the list simply remains empty.

```
login.attempt = datetime.date.today()  # this is the database entry I need to check for.
logins_today = DBLogin.query.filter_by(attempt = datetime.date.today()).all()
logins_today = DBLogin.query.filter(extract('day', DBLogin.attempt) == datetime.date.today()).all()
```

I'm expecting to get a list with database entries that match today's date, but what I get now is an empty list.

Comment: You have a `datetime` column correct?  Just run a SQL query with a `WHERE` clause.  Kinda of like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > CURDATE()`

Comment: Please take the time to add what is needed to make your question a [mcve]. Provide the required (parts of your) model, create test data, and clearly point out the expected vs. actual results. For example, do you ever add `login` to a `Session`, given that `login` is a model object.

Comment: I have tried using an SQL query like that, but it gives me a syntax error and unfortunately SQL3 gives these vague error messages of 'error near' instead of what is actually wrong. The query I have is this:
query = "SELECT * FROM main.db_login.db WHERE attempt = datetime.date.today() and success = FALSE"
Although I have also tried different statements for datetime.date.today() to see if those work. The error I get is this:
 "message": "Error: near \".\": syntax error"

Comment: Ilja, Yes I do add it to a session, and it appears in the database just fine. I can retrieve the database entries that have False for the variable success as well, so I doubt it's a problem with the database itself or how I commit the entries into it. I simply can't filter out the date.  As I mentioned in the question, I'm expecting a list of entries that match the date, but what I get is no error (well, unless I try SQL3), just an empty list

Comment: Update: After trying multiple other queries to see where the error arises, I believe the error may be due to the database name. However, I can't change that, because this is the database I need. I have tried to declare the database in a variable and call the variable instead, but that doesn't solve the error. Is there a way to somehow replace the '.' in the database name without it becoming the wrong name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my particular problem. It's not quite as optimal as I'd hoped, but it works for what I was trying to achieve. I'm posting it here in case other people struggle with a similar problem

Rather than trying to retrieve all the entries matching my search and putting them in a list, I'm working with the first one. It does mean that I can't check the amount of attempts within a time-setting, so I've introduced an extra variable to my database which I've called 'number', which I can keep track of and count, because the list works with other variables.

Then I'm using the time a user calls the function again and creating a var called sum which is the current datetime - the datetime from database. Finally I'm using a timedelta to check if the amount of time was more than 5 minutes
Now, I can check if the amount of time has passed and reset the 'number' variable in the database so that user's failed logins are reset on a successful login.

Of course, we do want to be able to see if a user's login was successful outside of just protecting brute-force attacks, so I've got another variable in my database called 'success' which is a boolean that doesn't reset once the user has logged in successfully.

I hope someone finds this solution helpful, because I was struggling with the problem quite a bit and couldn't find a suitable solution from the already present questions and comments on StackOverflow.